# Printf somehow changes something?

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, printf

Ok, so i have the following C code

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

// funkcija za mnozenje na dva 8-bitni broja (vo RC format) so Butov algoritam
// vlez:    a[] - mnozenik, b[] - mnozitel
// izlez:   proizvod[] - proizvodot (mnozenik * mnozitel)


void shiftRight(char niza[])
{
    char out[100];
    strncpy(out, niza, 1);
    strcat(out, niza);
    out[17]='\0';
    strcpy(niza, out);
}


void add(char opa[], char opb[])
{
    char rez[100];
    strcpy(rez, opa);
    char carry='0';
    int i=16;
    while(i>=0)
    {
        int car=carry-'0';
        int currbita=opa[i]-'0';
        int currbitb=opb[i]-'0';
        rez[i]=((car+currbita+currbitb)%2)+'0';
        if(car+currbita+currbitb>=2)
        {
            carry='1';
        }
        else
            carry='0';
        i--;
    }
    strcpy(opa, rez);
}

void vtorKomplement(char in[], char out[])
{
    strcpy(out, in);
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        if(out[i]=='0')
            out[i]='1';
        else
            out[i]='0';
    }
    int i=7;
    char carry='1';
    while(carry!='0')
    {
        int car=carry-'0';
        int currbit=out[i]-'0';
        if(car+currbit>=2)
        {
            carry='1';
        }
        else
            carry='0';
        out[i]=((car+currbit)%2)+'0';
        i--;
    }
}

void mnozenjeButov(char a[], char b[], char proizvod[]) {
    int i;
    char rez[100];
    char A[100];
    char S[100];
    char P[100];
    strcpy(A, a);
    strcat(A, "000000000");
    vtorKomplement(a, S);
    for(i=8; i<17; i++)
    {
        S[i]='0';
    }
    S[17]='\0';
    strcpy(P, "00000000");
    strcat(P, b);
    strcat(P, "0");
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        if(P[15]=='0'&& P[16]=='1')
        {
            add(P, A);
        }
        else if(P[15]=='1' && P[16]=='0')
        {
            printf("Before add P: %s\n", P);
            add(P, S);
        }
        shiftRight(P);
        printf("Shifted P: %s\n", P);
    }
    for(int i=8; i<17; i++)
    {
        proizvod[i-8]=P[i];
    }
    proizvod[8]='\0';
}

int main() {
    int success = 1;

    char a[100];
    char b[100];
    char proizvod[100];
    char w_proizvod[100];

    // TEST 1
    strcpy(a, "00010011");
    strcpy(b, "00000101");
    strcpy(w_proizvod, "01011111");
    mnozenjeButov(a, b, proizvod);
    printf("TEST 1: %s, %s\n", a, b);
    printf("  Tocen odgovor:    %s\n", w_proizvod);
    printf("  Vas odgovor:      %s\n", proizvod);

    if (strcmp(proizvod, w_proizvod) == 0) {
        printf("Vasata programa dava tocen rezultat :-)\n\n");
    } else {
        printf("Vasata programa dava netocen rezultat!\n\n");
        success = 0;
    }

    if (success == 1) {
        printf("Vasata programa gi pomina testovite uspesno!\n");
    } else {
        printf("Nekoi od testovite bea neuspesni.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

all is well and good, but something weird happens when i remove `printf("Before add P: %s\n", P);` and/or the printf after that. Then the output somehow changes, and some characters appear that shouldn't be there... I tried debugging, but then i get the normal output. I also tried testing on a different machine, and i also get the weird characters there. I've been banging my head for the last hour, can someone tell me where i'm going wrong? I'm using codeblocks with mingw GCC compiler.

Update:
Jens Gustedt's solution worked.

Comment: cant reproduce it with codelite - debug/release with/without the line gives the same result

Comment: Post a **minimal** complete example code! It’s a major hassle for us to reduce this to the relevant parts. Furthermore, I’m not surprised that this code has problems. It’s C++ in name only – you don’t take any advantage of the language, and use low-level operations throughout.

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but I don't like the `for(int i=8; i<17; i++)` bits. I mean, the rest is all multiples of 8, but `i<17` seems to go too far.

Comment: ok, there it is, left only one test for readability. i<17 is there to copy the '\0' character.

Comment: i took screenshots of the two different outputs
1. With printf: [link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/842/pic1yd.png/)
2. Without [link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/11/pic2gu.png/)

Comment: @KonradRudolph I thought you can use the exact same functions in c++ as you could in c, and you can still do low-level operations as you wish.
Changed the extension to .c and switched the includes , still getting the exact same output.

Comment: @FREEZX he means you should have tagged this as C code and wrote in the beginning in the post that it's C code.

As for your example as of this moment I can not reproduce what you say because I see nothing wrong with the code now. From the  comments I can deduce you have changed it. Please post a minimal example that reproduces your problem as Konrad said

Comment: You can, which doesn't mean you should.

Comment: @Lefteris i only have one call to mnozenjeButov. The problem occurs within that function.

Comment: @n.m. i was planning on making a class later on, which is why i named it .cpp. Anyways, i don't really think it's relevant to the problem, since after renaming it to .c and recompiling i still get the same problems.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with gdb?

Comment: @Kevin I did, stepping through gives me the right output. Running it with debug/continue gives the bad output, and so does running it with run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a conceptual error in these two lines:

```
strncpy(out, niza, 1);
strcat(out, niza);
```

`strncpy` here only copies exactly one character. In particular `out[0]` is equal to `niza[0]` and `out[1]` is whatever has been there before. Your `strcat` then writes `niza` to the next position where a 0-character is found, which can have catastrophic results. (The man page for `strncpy` says well so.)

To be able to do `strcpy` afterwards, you'd probably have to place a `'\0'` in there. But there is a much easier solution:

```
out[0] = niza[0];
strcpy(out + 1, niza);
```

Comment: If `strncpy` is the answer, you're probably asking the wrong question.  http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html

Comment: @KeithThompson the weird thing was, it worked well when i printed out stuff, but failed to do so when i didn't.

Comment: @FREEZX, if you have out of bounds write to your stack, anything can happen. And for such cases, if you have only little changes to the stack layout of your variables, seemingly big changes in behavior can occur.